# Why Blogger URL Related Post Undefined

Tags: javascript

I create a function using Javascript for related post on my Blogger template,

Here is my code:

```
function toHttps(link) { 
  var protocol=link.replace(/\:/g,''); 
  if(protocol=='http') { 
    var url=link.replace('http','https'); 
    return link.replace(url); 
  } 
}
```

if my original url is
https://dpawoncatering.blogspot.com/2008/08/nasi-box-murah.html

Why is the result like this?
https://dpawoncatering.blogspot.com/2008/08/undefined?

Comment: Because if the protocol is not http, the function doesn't return anything. Although it looks like only the filename is passed to the function so it won't work as you intend anyway.

Comment: Owh OK I see, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Naren Murali's answer is correct. I'd just like to add a different way of doing "protocol" swap using javascript's own URL parser that might be interesting for other people.

You can instantiate an `a` element and use its `href` attribute to parse your URL, then you can access and change the `protocol` attribute of the `href` and retrieve the resulting URL:

```
function toHttps(link) { 
  var url = document.createElement('a');
  url.href = link;
  url.protocol = 'https';
  return url.href;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the URL contains `https` already it does not enter the `if` condition, hence nothing is returned hence we get undefined, please check my corrected function. Let me know if you have any issues!

```js
function toHttps(link) { 
  if(link.indexOf('http://') > -1){ 
    var url=link.replace('http','https'); 
    return url; 
  } 
  return link
}
console.log(toHttps('http://dpawoncatering.blogspot.com/2008/08/nasi-box-murah.html'))
console.log(toHttps('https://dpawoncatering.blogspot.com/2008/08/nasi-box-murah.html'))
```